# How to predict which gas shows maximum ideal behavior at STP ? (given its critical temperature)

Tags: physical-chemistry, gas-laws

Suppose we know the Van Der Waals coefficients $a$ and $b$ for a set of gases in the real gas equation, then which is the correct method to predict which gas shows most ideal behavior at STP ?

Our professor said that we must check the critical temperature using the formula $$T_c=\frac{8a}{27Rb}$$ Then he said: "*The gas for which* $$|T_c-273|$$ is *minimum will show the most ideal behaviour*".

I sort of don't agree with this logic. Let us have a look at Andrew's curves:

[image]

We notice that greater is the temperature compared to critical temperature more is the ideal behaviour. So the correct method should be checking $(273-T_c)$. The gas which has **maximum** value of $(273-T_c)$ should show maximum ideal behaviour at $273 K$. Is my logic correct or not ? Why?

Comment: Its not clear why since a $T_c$ of $173$ and $373$ gives the same result. Presumably he means the one with the lowest $T_c$ in degrees Kelvin.

Comment: @porphyrin Yeah that is one problem. But the bigger problem is he said that difference between Tc and 273 should be minimum for ideal behavior. Shouldn't it be maximum for ideal behavior ?

Comment: Its just a conversion. Helium seem to have the lowest critical temp, $-268$ C or$ 5$ K, (hydrogen $33$ K, nitrogen $126$ K). Values seem to be mainly listed in centigrade not Kelvin, hence the $273$ is to convert. Can't see what $273$ has to do with it otherwise. Lowest temp (in K) should exhibit most ideal behaviour.

Comment: "Lowest temp (in K) should exhibit most ideal behaviour." <--- You mean the gas having lowest critical temperature shows most ideal behaviour at 273 K ? @porphyrin

Comment: I think you should read the question. "The most ideal behaviour at STP". If a gas has a high critical temperature, by the time it reaches STP, it would have deviated way too much from ideal behaviour.

Comment: If he did not use the absolute value Syntax, he would be correct.